# How to install MariaDB ColumnStore in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, columnstore

I have been trying to install MariaDB ColumnStore in my kuberentes cluster without any success. I just can't seem to find any information (which at least I can make sense of) on how to do it.

Previously I have installed the row base MariaDB using helm

```
 helm install stable/mariadb
```

Which installs everything correctly.

Is there a way to install ColumnStore using helm? By perhaps designing the values.yaml file?

Anyone who has done this before?

UPDATE:

This is what I tried doing instead.

```
 git clone https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-kubernetes

 helm install mariadb-enterprise --name my-cluster --set mariadb.cluster.topology=columnstore-standalone
```

But I get the error "Err:ImagePull"

```
 Events:
 Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
 ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
 Normal   Scheduled  33s                default-scheduler  Successfully 
 assigned default/my-cluster-mdb-cs-single-0 to minikube
 Warning  Failed     23s                kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull 
 image "mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error 
 response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: 
 lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:34210- 
 >10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
 Normal   BackOff    22s                kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling 
 image "mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3"
 Warning  Failed     22s                kubelet, minikube  Error: 
 ImagePullBackOff
 Normal   Pulling    10s (x2 over 33s)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image 
 "mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3"
 Warning  Failed     0s (x2 over 23s)   kubelet, minikube  Error: 
 ErrImagePull
 Warning  Failed     0s                 kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull 
 image "mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error 
 response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: 
 lookup 
 registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:59043->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Consider posting your output for what you have tried when installing. What happened? Error Codes? Anything?

Comment: Well after some more research, it does not appear to be any helm charts for columnStore, unless there is a way to modify the YAML file of the stable/mariadb chart to make the topology be columnStore.

Answer (score 0):

Helm default use the value.yaml file in root directory.

```
helm install -f myvalues.yaml ./helm-chart
```

You can donwload the mariaDB chart locally and edit it as per your need

> https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mariadb

After editing chart you can go inside the root directory of chart folder and apply command to install chart.

Comment: When looking at this link https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-kubernetes-parameters/ it looks like you should be able to "$ helm install . --set mariadb.cluster.topology=galera". But I don't understand what I should replace the "." with. I want something like "$ helm install mariadb --set mariadb.cluster.topology=columnstore"

Comment: you can do it like 'helm install . --set mariadb.cluster.topology=galera stable/mariadb'

Comment: all the parameter listed here on github you can check https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mariadb

Comment: They did not have that specific parameter, but I followed this instead. https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-kubernetes

Comment: try `helm install --name my-cluster --set mariadb.cluster.topology=columnstore-standalone mariadb-enterprise`

Comment: Yes, the same for me.

Comment: all the files are available on docker hub i have checked.

Comment: That's good, do you have any idea for a workaround then? Or why it might give this error?

Comment: add `--dry-run` before the install step in command . also check helm version on client & on cluster it's same `helm version`. `helm repo update`.

Comment: in value.yaml can try removing last 3 line.

Comment: It is the same version. But doing --dry-run does not install it, right?

Comment: Removing the last 3 lines did not help unfortunately.

Comment: Yes it will not install --dry-run

Comment: use it like `helm install --debug --dry-run` and your command

Comment: What should I be looking after when running this? To understand where the error lies? It seems to work well when I do the --dry-run

Comment: ohhh try installing again whole chart