# Error when trying to install MariaDB ColumnStore on Kubernetes using Helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mariadb, columnstore

I have tried to install MariaDB ColumnStore on Kubernetes. I am using Windows 10 and have my kubernetes cluster inside a VBox.

This is what I have tried so far:

First I went to https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-kubernetes/tree/master/mariadb-enterprise and downloaded the git repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-kubernetes
```

I CD to the directory of the folder and try to install the chart using Helm without any modification to the values file to see if it works.

```
helm install mariadb-enterprise/ --name my_cluster
```

It works. But when I try to change the topology to "columnstore"

```
helm install mariadb-enterprise/ --name my_cluster --set mariadb.cluster.topology = columnstore-standalone
```

I get the following error

```
my-cluster-mdb-cs-single-0              0/1     Init:ErrImagePull   0          18s
```

I get the following output when I use

```
 kubectl describe pod my-cluster-mdb-cs-single-0
```

---

```
 Name:               my-cluster-mdb-cs-single-0
 Namespace:          default
 Priority:           0
 PriorityClassName:  <none>
 Node:               minikube/10.0.2.15
 Start Time:         Wed, 19 Jun 2019 09:05:39 +0200
 Labels:             controller-revision-hash=my-cluster-mdb-cs-single- 
 84bcfc86b8
                mariadb=my-cluster
                pm.mariadb=my-cluster
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=my-cluster-mdb-cs-single-0
                um.mariadb=my-cluster
 Annotations:        <none>
 Status:             Pending
 IP:                 xxx.17.0.17
 Controlled By:      StatefulSet/my-cluster-mdb-cs-single
 Init Containers:
 init-columnstore:
     Container ID:
     Image:         mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3
     Image ID:
     Port:          <none>
     Host Port:     <none>
     Command:
       bash
       /mnt/config-template/init-configurations.sh
       columnstore
     State:          Waiting
       Reason:       ErrImagePull
     Ready:          False
     Restart Count:  0
     Environment:
      BACKUP_RESTORE_FROM:
      CLUSTER_TOPOLOGY:     columnstore-standalone
     Mounts:
      /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d from mariadb-entrypoint-vol (rw)
      /mnt/config-map from mariadb-config-vol (rw)
      /mnt/config-template from mariadb-configtemplate-vol (rw)
      /mnt/secrets from mariadb-secrets-vol (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-cv2g5 
(ro)
  init-volume:
    Container ID:
    Image:         mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      bash
      -c
      set -e; if [ ! -d "/mnt/columnstore/etc" ]; then rm -rf 
/mnt/columnstore/data && cp -rp /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/data 
/mnt/columnstore/ && rm -rf /mnt/columnstore/local && cp -rp 
/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/local /mnt/columnstore/ && rm -rf 
/mnt/columnstore/mysql && mkdir -p /mnt/columnstore/mysql && chown 
mysql:mysql /mnt/columnstore/mysql && cp -rp 
/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/db /mnt/columnstore/mysql/ &&cp -rp 
/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/etc /mnt/columnstore/; fi
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /mnt/columnstore from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-cv2g5 
(ro)
Containers:
  columnstore-module-pm:
    Container ID:
    Image:         mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3
    Image ID:
    Port:          3306/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      bash
      /mnt/config-map/start-mariadb-instance.sh
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
Environment:
  MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD:  Y
  CLUSTER_TOPOLOGY:            columnstore-standalone
Mounts:
  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d from mariadb-entrypoint-vol (rw)
  /mnt/config-map from mariadb-config-vol (rw)
  /tmp/data from temp-data (rw)
  /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/data from data (rw,path="data")
  /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/data1 from data (rw,path="data1")
  /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/data2 from data (rw,path="data2")
  /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/data3 from data (rw,path="data3")
  /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/etc from data (rw,path="etc")
  /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/local from data (rw,path="local")
  /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/db from data (rw,path="mysql/db")
  /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-cv2g5 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-my-cluster-mdb-cs-single-0
    ReadOnly:   false
    temp-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  temp-data-my-cluster-mdb-cs-single-0
    ReadOnly:   false
    mariadb-entrypoint-vol:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  mariadb-config-vol:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  mariadb-configtemplate-vol:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      my-cluster-mariadb-config
    Optional:  false
  mariadb-secrets-vol:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  my-cluster-mariadb-secret
    Optional:    false
  default-token-cv2g5:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-cv2g5
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  65s                default-scheduler  Successfully 
assigned default/my-cluster-mdb-cs-single-0 to minikube
  Warning  Failed     49s                kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull 
image "mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error 
response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup 
registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:57278->10.0.2.3:53: 
i/o timeout
  Normal   Pulling    35s (x2 over 65s)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image 
"mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3"
  Warning  Failed     25s (x2 over 49s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: 
ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     25s                kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull 
image "mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error 
response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup 
registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:34499->10.0.2.3:53: 
i/o timeout
  Normal   BackOff    15s (x2 over 48s)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling 
image "mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3"
  Warning  Failed     15s (x2 over 48s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: 
ImagePullBackOff
```

Anyone know why I get this error and if there is a way to solve it?

Comment: It seems your docker image is not getting pulled.

Comment: Any idea on a fix?

Comment: try to manually pull that image first `docker pull imagename`

Comment: "C:\Users\...\mariadb-kubernetes-master\mariadb-kubernetes-master>docker pull mariadb/columnstore:1.2.3
error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=mariadb%2Fcolumnstore&tag=1.2.3: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install MariaDB ColumnStore in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649206/how-to-install-mariadb-columnstore-in-kubernetes)

Comment: It's rather an extension of the old question, it felt like the discussion we had there was not very question specific.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I needed to have Docker installed on Windows. This was not possible when running minikube on VirtualBox. I had to reinstall minikube on Hyper-V, install Docker for Desktop, and then I could install MariaDB ColumnStore.